# Providing a restricted view into an input stream

Tags: c++, io

I am designing a parser for ELF files, which define named sections that divide it into pieces with individual offsets and sizes.

I'd like to use the standard library's `<iostream>` facilities to provide a standardized interface to all of my classes.  Most of the time, only certain sections of an ELF file are loaded, so it would be wasteful to load the entire file into memory and pass the parser a buffer.  Instead of that, what sort of input should it accept?  A `std::istream`, `std::streambuf`, a filename, or something else?

Further, some of these sections can be rather large, so I don't want to return a buffer when a user of the library asks for a particular section.  Ideally I want to provide a "restricted stream" so user code can access only the section of the ELF file that they requested.  Additionally, seeks/tells inside this restricted view would corrected for their offset inside the file.

How could I structure this code while maintaining compatibility with functions that accept streams?

Comment: Maybe you could read through the ELF creating an in-memory *index* of symbols. Then, when the user requests one, read just that part into a `std::stringstream` and pass that to the user?

Comment: Sounds like you need to create (or find) a custom `filebuf` that has a starting and ending index.  Open the file, seek to the starting index, and don't read past the ending index.  Then you can assign that `filebuf` to a standard `std::istream`.